# Laravel : How to pass all the value of my string/array into view?

Tags: laravel

I hope somebody can help me with this.
I am trying to pass a data from the controller into view. When I tried to var_dump the variable it contains all the data that I need.

For example, when I var_dump($data);
the result were, data1 data2 data3 and more...

But, when I pass it to my view, I am only getting data1.
I tried to changed my variable into array or string but still I am getting the same problem.

Code in my controller:

```
if((substr_count($value, $let1) <= $count1) && (substr_count($value, $let2) <= $count2)      && (substr_count($value, $let3) <= $count3) && (substr_count($value, $let4) <= $count4)){

 $data = $value; 

 return View::make('result')
 ->with('this', $data);
}
```

Code in my view:

```
@if(!empty($this))
var_dump($this);                    
@endif
```

the result will always be the first data of my array/string..
BUT when I tried this code

```
if($countthis == 4){    
if((substr_count($value, $let1) <= $count1) && (substr_count($value, $let2) <= $count2)   && (substr_count($value, $let3) <= $count3) && (substr_count($value, $let4) <= $count4)){

$data = $value; 

var_dump ($data);

}
```

I am getting all the data that I need.
Please help me. I am a new to Laravel and PHP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe not related, but I would avoid using "this" as the name for the data you are passing to the view. `$this` has a special meaning in PHP. Try calling it something a little more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried to change it but it doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: Yeah, I thought it probably wouldn't. You should still change it, though. Using `$this` in any context other than in an object is going to confuse anyone looking at your code.

Comment: Yes, I already changed it. I wasn't aware about it. Thank you.

Comment: This is likely related to something else in your controller or view. You should post the contents of both files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :

```
return View::make('result', compact('data'));

@if(!empty($this))
   var_dump($data);                    
@endif
```

If you want a different name ($data) do this :

```
$yourName = $value;

return View::make('result', compact('yourName'));
```

The point is that Laravel is waiting for 1 global array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
return view('home', compact('array_var'))->with('str_var', $value);
```